# SQL case query not giving correct values

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, case-when

**First set of query:**

```
select count(distinct device_ifa) from table_1 where distance_diff <= 50  --  41504

select count(distinct device_ifa) from table_1  where distance_diff <= 100  --  69469

select count(distinct device_ifa) from table_1 where distance_diff <= 200  --  100859
```

**should exactly match the counts of the query:**

```
select case when distance_diff <= 50 then '50m'
            when distance_diff <= 100 then '100m'
            when distance_diff <= 200 then '200m' 
       end as radius, 
       count(distinct device_ifa) from table_1 
group by 1 order by 1


radius  _col1

100m   -    62512
200m    -   92547
50m      -   41504
```

**But the counts are not matching - can anyone help plz.**

Comment: Can you try using `select '50m' as radius, count(distinct ...) ... where distance_diff <= 50 UNION ALL select '100m' as radius, count(distinct ...) ... where distance_diff <= 100 UNION ALL select '200m' as radius, count(distinct ...) ... where distance_diff <= 200`?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that will give different results when you run individually and with case statement. Individually will give accurate count which you mentioned while case statement will give the data in this way ..

select case when distance_diff <= 50 then '50m' --will give the data for less than 50
            when distance_diff <= 100 then '100m' -- will give the data between 50 and 100 as the results were already included as part of 50M 
            when distance_diff <= 200 then '200m' --this will give between 100 and 200 as < 100 is already part of above statement.

To get accurate count you can write case statement in this way

```
select 
       count(distinct case when distance_diff <= 50  then  device_ifa end ) 
Less_than_50, count(distinct case when distance_diff <= 100  then  device_ifa end ) 
Less_than_100 , count(distinct case when distance_diff <= 200  then  device_ifa end ) 
Less_than_200 from  table_1 
group by 1 order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The Reason you getting different count is because of CASE statement functionality.

```
case when distance_diff <= 50 then '50m'
        when distance_diff <= 100 then '100m'
        when distance_diff <= 200 then '200m' 
   end as radius
```

when you run above query where there is an overlap in data (e.g. <=100 condition also  include <=50 , and similar for <=200.).

How the above query behave?:

1.distance_Diff <= 50   : This will mark all the distance_diff value from 0 to 50 as '50m'

2.distance_Diff <= 100   : This will mark all the distance_diff value from 51 to 100 as '100m'

3.distance_Diff <= 200   : This will mark all the distance_diff value from 101 to 200 as '200m'

So condition 1 will executed first. then it will check for the remaining untagged value for 2nd condition and then last 3rd condition will execute.

where as in your first query where you are taking separate count is including overlap values as well.

```
select count(distinct device_ifa) from table_1 where distance_diff <= 50  --  41504
```

Above query count distance_diff from 0 to 50.

```
select count(distinct device_ifa) from table_1  where distance_diff <= 100  --  69469
```

Above query count distance_diff from 0 to 100.

```
select count(distinct device_ifa) from table_1 where distance_diff <= 200  --  100859
```

Above query count distance_diff from 0 to 200.

I hop this is clear now why the results are different in both the query.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking why these are returning different results.

The reason is simple.  A `distance_diff` of 25 is counted in all three groups in the first query.  It is counted only in the `< 50` group for the second.

The first returns a cumulative distinct count.  The second returns a distinct count just for the range.

The results should match if you change the individual queries filter for the specific ranges:

```
where distance_diff <= 50
where distance_diff > 50 distance_diff <= 100
where distance_diff > 100 distance_diff <= 200
```